# AJAX callback in Obj constructor

Tags: javascript, ajax, constructor, geocoding, gdata-api

I have a class object called Location that works with Google in order to geocode a given address.
The geocode request is made trough an AJAX call and handled via a callback that will initiate the class members once the response arrives.

Here is the code:

```
function Location(address) {
    this.geo = new GClientGeocoder();
    this.address = address;
    this.coord = [];

    var geoCallback = function(result) {
        this.coord[0] = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1];
        this.coord[1] = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0];
        window.alert("I am in geoCallback() lat: " + this.coord[0] + "; lon: " + this.coord[1]);
    }

    this.geo.getLocations(this.address, bind(this, geoCallback));                   
}
Location.prototype.getAddress = function() { return this.address; }
Location.prototype.getLat = function() { return this.coord[0] }
Location.prototype.getLng = function() { return this.coord[1] }
```

My question is: it's possible to wait the response from Google **before** exiting the constructor?

I have no control over the AJAX request since it's made trough Google APIs.

I want to be sure that `this.coord[]` is properly initialized once a Location obj is created.

Thank you!

Comment: What are these property getters good for? Every property you give `this` is public. You could easily drop the getters and use the properties directly (just make distinct `Lat` and `Lng` properties instead of a `coord` array).

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't (read: should not) wait. This is why it's called AJAX ("Asynchronous Javascript ...") in the first place. ;)

You could use a callback function yourself (untested code ahead).

```
function Location(address, readyCallback) {
  this.geo = new GClientGeocoder();
  this.address = address;
  this.coord = [];
  this.onready = readyCallback;

  this.geo.getLocations(this.address, bind(this, function(result) {
    this.coord[0] = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1];
    this.coord[1] = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0];
    if (typeof this.onready == "function") this.onready.apply(this);
  }));
}
Location.prototype.getAddress = function() { return this.address; }
Location.prototype.getLat = function() { return this.coord[0] }
Location.prototype.getLng = function() { return this.coord[1] }

// ... later ...

var l = new Location("Googleplex, Mountain View", function() {
  alert(this.getLat());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to wait the response
>   from Google before exiting the
>   constructor?

I wouldn't recommend this approach. When you create a JavaScript object, you don't normally expect it to block for hundreds of milliseconds, until Google responds.

In addition, Google will throttle the `GClientGeocoder` if you attempt to do frequent requests ([Source](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoStatusCode.G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES)). There is also a cap for the number of requests a client can do in 24 hours. This would be complicated to handle systematically using this approach. You could easily get into a debugging nightmare if you will be having JavaScript objects that fail randomly.